# While deploying Aura component I am getting the error: No COMPONENT named markup://c:arMyCustomComponent found

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am trying to embed my LWC component inside Aura component but when I am trying to deploy Aura component I am getting the error: No COMPONENT named markup://c:arMyCustomComponent found

This is my Aura component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" access="global">
   <c:arMyCustomComponent objectApiName="Order" recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
</aura:component>
```

In my LWC component HTML I have only this and the name of my LWC is **ar_myCustomComponent**:

```
<h1> Hello </h1>
```

Could you please tell me why I am getting this error and how can it bee resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Since the name of your LWC component is **ar_myCustomComponent** and in your aura component you have it as **armyCustomComponent**, you will need to make sure the LWC component is renamed to **armyCustomComponent**